# How to Install pre-requisites with setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I have pure python package that relies on 3 other python packages:
I'm using distutils.core.setup to do the installation.

This is my code from setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.2',
    scripts=['myscript'],
    packages=['mypackage'],
    install_requires=[
        'netifaces > 0.5',
        'IPy > 0.75',
        'yaml > 3.10'])
```

I specified the modules I need with install_requires, but it seems to have no effect when I run

```
python ./setup.py install
```

How can I ensure that the modules that mypackage depends on are installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distutils` has no functionality for downloading, or even verifying, prerequisites; its `install_requires` is only there for documentation.

If you want that, you need the third-party library [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Most people already have `setuptools`, and hopefully `pip`, and will be using them to install your package anyway (assuming you plan to distribute over PyPI), but if you include the `setuptools` bootstrap, it will take care of installing `setuptools` if needed to install those dependencies.